# Crear botón volver página anterior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con *VueJS* en *Quasar* y quisiera crear un botón que me permita regresar a la página anterior. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Este es el div donde contengo el botón:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 row justify-end">
   <q-btn flat class="btnReturn" label="Volver" icon="keyboard_arrow_left" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregale `@click="$router.go(-1)"` al boton.

> (probado en `vue 3` con `vue router 4`. Según documentación debería funcionar en `vue router 3` también): https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n

```
 <q-btn 
   flat 
   class="btnReturn" 
   label="Volver" 
   icon="keyboard_arrow_left"
   @click="router.go(-1)"
 />
```

Otra forma usando javascript puro (sin vue router) sería creando un método `retroceder` y enlazarlo al evento `click` del botón:

```
<q-btn 
   flat 
   class="btnReturn" 
   label="Volver" 
   icon="keyboard_arrow_left"
   @click="retroceder()"
 />
```

> Vue 2

```
methods: {
   retroceder(){
     window.history.back();
   }
}
```

> Vue 3

```
setup(){
   const retroceder = () => {
       window.history.back();
   }

   return { retroceder } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó